# Converting index of one dimensional array into two dimensional array i. e. row and column

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I have one application of `WinForms` which inside list box I am inserting name and price..name and price are stored in two dimensional array respectively. Now when I select one record from the `listbox` it gives me only one index from which I can get the string name and price to update that record I have to change name and price at that index for this I want to update both two dimensional array name and price. but the selected index is only one dimensional. I want to convert that index into row and column. How to do that?

But I'm inserting record in list box like this.

```
int row = 6, column = 10;
for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<column;j++)
    {
        value= row+" \t "+ column +" \t "+ name[i, j]+" \t " +price[i, j];
        listbox.items.add(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably post some code....

Answer (score 43, accepted):

While I didn't fully understand the exact scenario, the common way to translate between 1D and 2D coordinates is:

From 2D to 1D:

```
index = x + (y * width)
```

or

```
index = y + (x * height)
```

depending on whether you read from left to right or top to bottom.

From 1D to 2D:

```
x = index % width
y = index / width
```

or

```
x = index / height
y = index % height
```

Comment: How to do it for multidimensional arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
int i = OneDimensionIndex%NbColumn
int j = OneDimensionIndex/NbRow //Care here you have to take the integer part
```

Comment: This is correct if the source array contains a sequence like `name price name price ...`. This, however, is not a real two-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understand you correctly, in your case, obviously the index of the `ListBox` entry's array entry is the index in the `ListBox`. The name and price are then at index `0` and index `1` of that array element.

Example:

```
string[][] namesAndPrices = ...;

// To fill the list with entries like "Name: 123.45"
foreach (string[] nameAndPrice in namesAndPrices)
   listBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("{0}: {1}", nameAndPrice[0], nameAndPrice[1]));

// To get the array and the name and price, it's enough to use the index
string[] selectedArray = namesAndPrices[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
string theName = selectedArray[0];
string thePrice = selectedArray[1];
```

If you have an array like that:

```
string[] namesAndPrices = new string[] { "Hello", "123", "World", "234" };
```

Things are different. In that case, the indices are

```
int indexOfName = listBox1.SelectedIndex * 2;
int indexOfPrice = listBox1.SelectedIndex * 2 + 1;
```

Comment: How about changing the question adding relevant parts of your source code? This is *not* something to be posted in the comments.