# Sequential fill of an array of unknown dimensions

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, performance, multidimensional-array

I have an `Array` of unknown dimensions. E.g. it may be `object[]`, `object[,]`, `object[,,,]`.

I want to fill it sequentially (e.g. for [2,2] this order: 0,0; 0,1, 1,0; 1,1):

```
Array arr = ... // input array
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
     arr.SetValue(stream.ReadNextObject(), ???); // convert i -> int[] indexes
}
```

I know that the conversation of `i` can be done with `%` operator but it's hard to imagine an exact algorithm for multiple dimensions. There is only an answer for two-dimensions: [Converting index of one dimensional array into two dimensional array i. e. row and column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790584/converting-index-of-one-dimensional-array-into-two-dimensional-array-i-e-row-a)

I could use `Stack<int>` to store indexes while walking an array but it seems that `%` will be more efficient (I really need to care about performance here). But I'm not sure about `Stack<T>` vs `%`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You want to read objects from a stream and store them in an array? `i` is already going over every possible index in your array, why don't you use `arr.SetValue(stream.ReadNextObject(), i);`?

Comment: @AudricdeSchaetzen that only works for 1 dimensional array

Comment: Sounds like `switch`/`case`. Why array is of unknown dimensions? How and from where you get it?

Comment: @Sinatr it's a serializer library. An array is created using reflection.

Comment: You can use recursion (because each dimension is a nested loop), check if item is of enumerable type (not sure if `IEnumerable` is the most *basic*) and if it is - then run same method recursively for this element. This will work for jagged array `List<List<List<...>>>`. Not sure what to do with multidimensional arrays though.

Comment: @TamasIonut You're right, the post had been updated between my first reading it and posting my comment. I should have noticed.

Comment: @Sinatr yes, it's the same as `Stack<int>` approach but less efficient.

Comment: Do you know dimension in advance? Or shall it be heuristically determined? Making a method with 2 parameters: something iteratable and number of dimensions should be a trivial task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the algorithm that I believe you are looking for

```
public static int[] SingleIndexToMulti(int index, int[] dimentionSizes)
{
    var result = new int[dimentionSizes.Length];
    for (int i = dimentionSizes.Length - 1; i >=0; i--)
    {
        result[i] = index % dimentionSizes[i];
        index = index / dimentionSizes[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

You would use it like this

```
Array myArray = Whatever();
int[] dimensionSizes = new int[myArray.Rank];
for(int i =0; i < myArray.Rank; i++)
    dimensionsSizes[i] = myArray.GetLength(i);
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    arr.SetValue(stream.ReadNextObject(), SingleIndexToMulti(i, dimensionSizes)); 
}
```

To demonstrate the following code

```
for(int i=0; i < (2*3*4) ;i++)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", SingleIndexToMulti(i, new[] { 2, 3, 4 })));
```

Produces

> 0,0,0
>
> 0,0,1
>
> 0,0,2
>
> 0,0,3
>
> 0,1,0
>
> 0,1,1
>
> 0,1,2
>
> 0,1,3
>
> 0,2,0
>
> 0,2,1
>
> 0,2,2
>
> 0,2,3
>
> 1,0,0
>
> 1,0,1
>
> 1,0,2
>
> 1,0,3
>
> 1,1,0
>
> 1,1,1
>
> 1,1,2
>
> 1,1,3
>
> 1,2,0
>
> 1,2,1
>
> 1,2,2
>
> 1,2,3

Comment: Yes, this is the algorithm I was looking for so I've accepted it. Until you posted this I couldn't even compare it with stack approach but now I see that using stack should be more efficient so I've chosen that way.

Answer (score 0):

I have a recursive solution for you:

```
void Fill(Array a, Stream stream)
{
    int[] indices = new int[a.Rank]; // c# should initialize this with 0s
    FillRecursive(a, indices, 0, stream)    
}
void FillRecursive(Array a, int[] indices, int rank, Stream stream)
{
    for (int idx = 0; idx < a.GetLength(rank); idx++)
    {
        indices[rank] = idx;
        if (rank == a.Rank - 1)
            a.SetValue(stream.ReadNextObject(), indices);
        else
            FillRecursive(a, indices, rank + 1, stream);
    }
}
```

This should do the trick. I count up the individual dimensions and continously set the value. *Note* that `Stream` is kind of pseudo code (my `Stream` does not have a `ReadNextObject`).

I admit that I had no time to really test it. And I leave the performance measurements up to you, but I don't think there is a much faster alternative.

**UPDATE**: Test it, and it fills the "cells" in the correct order as you expected it. I testet it using an `int[3,3,3]` and a `ReadNextValue` that returns increasing integers. Result:

```
[0,0,0] => 0
[0,0,1] => 1
[0,0,2] => 2
[0,1,0] => 3
[0,1,1] => 4
...
[2,2,0] => 24
[2,2,1] => 25
[2,2,2] => 26
```

Note that this works not only for arbitrary dimensions, but also for arbitrary and different lengths of the individual dimensions.